# How to run .NET x86 tests on linux

Tags: .net, linux, testing, x86

I have x86 projects forced by 3rd party dlls.

This is a part of test project's csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Running tests on Windows is working just fine.

[image: dotnet info on windows]

Running tests WSL Ubuntu gives me however different result:

[image: dotnet test on wsl]

There is an older SDK installed, but still it should work

[image: dotnet info on linux]

And last but not least there is an error running the tests on Ubuntu in GitHub Actions

[image: Github actions test run]

Github workflow setup:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    timeout-minutes: 10

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
```

My question is how to run x86 tests on linux and mainly with Github Actions